# JVM Server OR Standalone scripts

Tags: application-server, kaazing

Are ActiveMQ and Kaazing jms installed on local Mac OS running on any JVM by default [how can i get that info] or standalone start scripts. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bee,

When you download and extract the gateway (I recommend you to get the "Gateway + Demos" packaging for Linux/Unix/Mac - it contains Apache ActiveMQ preconfigured with the gateway, in addition to the documentation and out-of-the-box demos), you'll find a README.txt file in the root directory. It lists the Java requirements.

For your convenience, here's the Java Requirements snippet from the 4.0.3 version of the gateway:

> Java Requirements
>
> ```
> * Java Developer Kit (JDK) or Java Runtime Environment (JRE)
>   Java 7 (version 1.7.0_21) or higher
> * The JAVA_HOME environment variable must be set to the directory where 
>   the JDK is installed, for example C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21
> * Note:
>   * For information on installing JDK, see Oracle's Java SE documentation:
>     http://download.oracle.com/javase/.
> ```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Peter, Thanks for your reply. However, where i am stuck is the entry point for starting kaazing jms application. Actually, i want to run my kaazing jms application using some javaagent but i am not able to figure out where is the main class for the same to refer. I checked jconsle to verify the same and it shows "com.kaazing.gatway.server.Main". So can you help me out with the location of the main class which i can pass in my command.

Comment: or if i can run kaazing using java from the command line like         >> java  /Users/xxx/GATEWAY_HOME/bin/gateway.start

Comment: The gateway.start script does pretty much what you're looking for. It sets up a handful of environment variables, and then it starts the com.kaazing.gateway.server.Main class.

And just to clarify, when you ask: "where i am stuck is the entry point for starting kaazing jms application." you mean starting the Kaazing WebSocket Gateway, the server product to serve WebSocket requests, correct?